# Best method for storing images in a database for Android Galley App

Tags: android, mysql, image, gallery, android-glide

What would be the best way of storing images in a database? What i'm trying to do is:

- android app that displays all pictures stored in a specific place, using Glide library(i have a MySQL online database + file hosting)
- ability to upload new pictures into said database

Should I use blobs or upload the files directly on the Host? Is there a way to get the file location and send them via JSON to Glide?

Comment: there are plenty examples on the internet about your case how ever you store the image in the server and in the database you store the link , and in your code you put the link of the image only

Comment: best method is not to

Comment: @Moudiz Would it be possible to get the link to new pictures added automatically into the database, when they are uploaded to the database folder? Php maybe?

Comment: yes you ca ndo that ofcourse